# Is it possible to gain read access to HDD firmwares to check its integrity?

Tags: firmware

Is it possible to gain read access to HDD firmware to check if the integrity of the firmware is intact in case of suspected firmware infection in some way on GNU/Linux? Like I can see my HDD firmware details by this `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`
And is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many harddrive vendors implement methods to update and verify the updated firmware, but that is highly vendor dependent. You either need a vendor-supplied tool, or to reverse engineer this tool to figure out the protocol. As long as you follow the protocol or use the vendor-supplied tool, it is fairly safe, especially if you just verify the firmware (or manage to download it from the drive). Updating the firmware needs the usual precautions, e.g., interrupting the flash process or power cycling too early can brick your harddisk.

Sometimes tools and firmware can be found on the website of the vendor. Sometimes they can be found elsewhere by googling a bit, like [here](http://files.hddguru.com/index.php). Use at your own risk.

If you have JTAG hardware, you can also try direct access. This can brick your drive if done wrong, so it's not safe unless you know what you are doing. Google ["reverse engineer harddrive"](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+engineer+harddrive) for some entertaining writeups, for example [this](https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/04/hard-disk-firmware-hacking-part-1.html) one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times, the difference in performance is given by the drivers and not by the hardware.

For example, NVIDIA GPUs work better in Linux using the propietary driver instead of the open source drivers provided by Nouveau.

If Nvidia would open their drivers, their competitors could learn techniques to get on the same level of performance.

Comment: What does proprietary drivers have to do with read access to the firmware of a device?

Comment: The firmware of the device is the gate that communicates hardware and driver. Opening the firmware is like giving full access to all the intricate methods that your software engineers developed through months to get faster speeds, more precision,etc.

Comment: Original question was not regarding performance but regarding security and that the firmware hadn't been tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the latest updater from the manufacturer, if the manufacturer released a firmware for it.  I have never applied one for a hard drive, but I have for optical drives and other devices.  Theoretically, that will give you the correct firmware from the manufacturer.

Comment: The problem in that is that the new firmware installation must usually happen through the functions of the old firmware. An evil firmware could have a modified update function that would simply receive the new firmware data, check its version number, and then start reporting the version number of the new firmware and ignore the rest of the update.